# Roo install i18n

Tags: spring-roo

when trying to create a i18n addon :

roo > addon create i18n --topLevelPackage com.gilles.photos.addon --locale ic --messageBundle i18n/messages_ic.properties

I get the message :

```
Command 'addon create i18n --topLevelPackage com.gilles.photos.addon --locale ic --messageBundle i18n/messages_ic.properties' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

I try to follow the recommandations of this post : 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?101843-addon-create-i18n-does-not-work

The advices of the guy are opaque to me. What does he mean by  :

> The addon create commands need to be
>   run in an empty directory

There are no clear answer available on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you exactly trying to do? To install support for a given language; use

```
web mvc install language --code it
```

Where `it` is the code of the language. "Roo currently support six languages, and you can write an add-on language for others of your choice" - as of February, 2011. The command you were trying is the one that's supposed to create an addon for a language which is not yet supported. (I don't think that's your intention)

EDIT after question clarification:

See [roo documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/index.html#simple-addons), section A.5.2.
What you have to do is

- acquire an existing messages_xx.properties (checkout roo source and find them here: ..\addon-web-mvc-jsp\src\main\resources\org\springframework\roo\addon\web\mvc\jsp\i18n\languages)
- from one of these files, create the _ic.properties.
- crate a subdirectory called i18n in an empty directory, place messages_ic.properties there
- issue the command you tried: `addon create i18n --topLevelPackage foo.bar --locale ic --messageBundle i18n/messages_ic.properties`

Comment: I am trying to create a language addon, so I can get Icelandic support for my application.